# Data augmentation by adding noise in python regression model

Tags: regression, machine-learning, python, data-augmentation

I am building a regression model for a target variable which is heavy tailed. I want to augment data so that the model gets enough training samples in the region where it's a long tail. Accuracy of prediction for the rare data points is important.
The distribution of my target variable is heavy tailed , i.e. I have very few samples for the highest values of my target variable (and those highest values are the most important to predict correctly).

I am currently augmenting data by adding noise to the training samples. After splitting into train and test, I do MinMaxScaler on all the features(X), but no scaling on the target variable(y). Then, I add noise to both X and y with different mean and std since X is scaled to [0,1] but y isn't. Here is the code for augmenting by adding noise

```
def add_noise(mean, std, df):
    noise = np.random.normal(mean, std, df.shape)
    df2= df.where(df <= 0.001 , df.add(abs(noise)))
    return df2
```

I invoke this using something like add_noise(0,0.005,X_train) and add_noise(0,1,y_train) X_train is normalized/scaled so I can use a small std deviation. Now I have to decide what std deviation of y_train will cause only a small perturbation that corresponds to the perturbation to X_train.

Questions:

1. How do I find the right mean and std for my y variable - keeping in mind that the model should see similar data distribution between the original dataset and the augmented one?
2. Any other suggestions on augmenting data for regression ?

Comment: What is heavy-tailed, the pooled distribution of all values of your target variable?

Comment: Adding Normally distributed noise conflicts with your characterization of the variable as "heavy tailed."  Could you therefore explain to us what you mean by this term "heavy tailed"?

Comment: yes, the distribution of my target variable is heavy tailed , i.e. I have very few samples for the highest values of my target variable (and those highest values are the most important to predict correctly)

Comment: Can you please edit your post to include that new information? Not everybody reads comments.

Comment: I agree @whuber that it's not perfectly correct to add gaussian noise. Any other suggestion of augmenting data? SMOTE doesn't work since it's not classification and implementation of smogn seems to be failing for me